# Fix Arel Error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone = integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

Trying to perform an Arel query. In my params I have 
`{"node"=>"firstSeenAt", "rule"=>"hasAnyValue", "value"=>""}` where `first_seen_at` is a column in my `visitors` table

```
def table
   visitors.arel_table
end
```

```
def rule_has_any_value
   visitors.where(table["#{column}"].not_in_any(["", nil, 0]))
end
```

keep getting this in my Rails console

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone = integer
LINE 1: ... IN (NULL) OR "visitors"."first_seen_at" NOT IN (0)) OR...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
):
```

Any pointers on what's wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: I think the issue here is that you are trying to match a column with timestamp type with integer type.

Comment: Would you mind providing more details? For example, what are the columns in your `visitors` table. Also, it may help if you explain more about what the intention of your `rule_has_any_value` method. There may be a better way of modelling this.